# Mysql INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I'm trying to do the following query in mysql 5.5

```
INSERT INTO countingTable( image_count, article_id ) 

SELECT COUNT( article_id ) AS sum, article_id
FROM imageTable 

ON DUPLICATE  KEY UPDATE image_count = VALUES(sum)
```

But this gives the error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'sum' in 'field list'
```

Edit for better explaining what i like to do:

countingTable structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countigTable` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `plakat` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_count` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trailer_count` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `actor_count` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   .... (many more counting fields)
  `article_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `article_id` (`article_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

imageTable has the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imageTable` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `article_id` (`article_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

(imageTable is basically a referencing table for many2many relation)

The countingTable already has rows referencing the article_id.
Now i like to count all related images and insert or update that in the
countingTable.

Later i need the same stuff for trailer_count, actor_count and so on.

If this is done the first time, the countingTable will be updated by triggers.

The idea is, to have this table so I dont't need to join all relations just for counting if they exist. (As my project needs the countings all the time)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `UPDATE image_count = VALUES(image_count)`.

`VALUES()` expects a name from the columns you are inserting into, not the alias in the query. The query should be:

```
INSERT INTO countingTable (image_count, article_id) 

SELECT COUNT(article_id) AS sum, article_id
FROM imageTable 
GROUP BY article_id                  -- I suppose you skipped that line?

ON DUPLICATE  KEY UPDATE image_count = VALUES(image_count) ;
```

If you want the new values to be added to the existing ones, use:

```
...
ON DUPLICATE  KEY UPDATE image_count = image_count + VALUES(image_count) ;
```

Comment: Thanks. That works somehow but does not do what i want to do. I like to have the sum value updated on rows that already have this artcle_id and a new row it there is no row with this article_id. Your tip doesn't do that. But it fixes the error in my query.

Comment: You want the two values (existing and new) added in that case? See the edit.

Comment: And I think you missed the `GROUP BY article_id` line from the query.

Comment: I have edited the question. Perhaps it is more clear now what i like to get.

Comment: Argghhh. You are right. I forgot the GROUP BY. Did that and everything worked as expected. Thank you!